# How to animate color transitions in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm creating a custom checkbox-like widget that uses `Card`. I'm able to get the colors changing if the values are the same `onTap`. However, I want it to transition the color instead of it suddenly changing.

Here's my code:

```dart
return Card(
      color: selected ? AppColors.primary : AppColors.primaryLight,
```

I'm relatively new to animations in Flutter, but coming from a strong Frontend/CSS understanding, the way I could achieve something like this is to add `transition` on a CSS property -- is there something similar to this in Flutter? If not, could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What I would do is instead of using the `Card` widget, I would use an `AnimatedContainer` and have the same condition as you for the color parameter. You will get a smooth transition when the `selected` value changes. However, you may need to also add `boxShadow` to have the same elevation effect as `Card`

```dart
AnimatedContainer(
 duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 700),
 curve: Curves.easeInOut,
 decoration:BoxDecoration(
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.black,
        blurRadius: 5,
        spreadRadius: 5,
        offset: Offset(0, 2),
      ),
    ],
    color: selected ? AppColors.primary : AppColors.primaryLight,
    ),
   )
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be an [AnimatedContainer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html)

```
return Card(
        child: AnimatedContainer(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
          height: 200,
          width: 200,
          color: selected ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
          child: FooWidget(),
        ),
      )
```